# Moonkeps PC program

Tags: orbital-elements

Does anyone know where I could obtain a program called Moonkeps? It was an old MsDos based program that produced, I believe, the Keplerian elements for tracking the Moon and also the Sun. I wish to control a rotator for tracking the Sun for a project I am messing with. Dave.

Comment: There are several questions about tracking the Sun and Moon with good answers here. If you would like to explore something besides MsDos, then you have a lot of options. Have a look at these [1](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/27749/7982), [2](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/18029/7982), [3](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/27961/7982) and see if anything there looks useful. If you mention more about what you are doing I am sure there are more ways to do this.

Comment: http://www.amsat.org/amsat/ftp/software/PC/tracking/moonkeps.zip is presumably it, but I agree that there are much better ways to do this now.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the replies. I am trying to use things that I already have. I have a program and interface called Fodtrack. This utilises a printer port and also will not run under Win 10. I have an old laptop that still has Win 95 so will run the Dos program ok and it also has the printer port too, so I was trying to press these items into service. I have tried the Amsat link to the Moonkeps.zip, but the site is not available. Dave.

Comment: Hello. Maybe I should add. Years ago, I used to be a member of a group called RIG and track weather satellites to display the live pictures on a pc. I built a rotator and fitted a 1 meter dish, to track hi-res HRPT satellites, but never followed it through. So i’m planning to cover the dish with silver Mylar, or maybe have it silvered/ chromed to make it reflective and place a small Stirling engine at the focus, hence the need to track the Sun.

Comment: You might also find it very interesting to explore [Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

It can be obtained from the internet archive of amsat ftp server.

https://web.archive.org/web/20120412030910/https://www.amsat.org/amsat/ftp/software/PC/tracking/moonkeps.zip